# which class returns the logging method when inheriting multiple classes python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have 3 classes, 2 parent and 1 child that inherits from both parents:

```
import logging
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_logger = logging.getLogger("parent")
        
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_logger = logging.getLogger("parent")
        
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        
test_class = C()
test_class.parent_logger.info("sample")
```

Which class does the `parent_logger` get used from when instantiating class C and calling parent logger on it?

Answer (score 1):

The order is left to right, so in this case the logger gets used from class A, because you declared C as inheriting from `(A, B)`. First A is searched for the logger, then all its parent classes (if it has any) and then B. If you defined C as `class C(B, A):` then B would be searched first and the logger from B would be used.

https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-mro-in-python